# React PropTypes and child properties

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

So I have a generic Modal component I have created. This modal may or may not have a form, depending on if a "form" property is provided. My intention, using PropTypes validation, is to have the name of the form be required IF the form property is provided. This is my PropTypes code:

```
form: PropTypes.shape({
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func,
  initialValues: PropTypes.object
}),
```

So, this does work to enforce the requirement to have a name when using the "form" property. However, when the "form" property is not provided, I get a warning in the console saying that it's missing the required form.name property.

I want it to be where "form" is optional, but if "form" is provided, "name" is required. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This should work the way you expect. My guess is that you are passing an empty object for `form` and not `null`? That's why you are getting the warning. Maybe even in `defaultProps`?

Comment: You can create a custom propType as outlined [in the documentation for the `customProp` example](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes).